# Migrating from .NET 2.0 to .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

What are the changes I need to make to a  application built with .NET 2.0 /C# in order to use the C# 4.0 features . Recently I ran into a problem, when trying to add optional paramters in a product which was developed on .NET 2.0 / C# 2.0 .

Comment: And that problem is what exactly ... ?

Comment: Make sure your production server has 4.0 installed and your App Pool is using 4.0 (this was a manual step).  The web.config and other things were upgraded in the Wizard, but using ReSharper I ended up having to make a handful of other changes...

Answer (score 2):

Most 2.0 programs works without any changes on 4.0. It was only on 1.1 to 2.0 that there was a lot of incompatible changes.

Answer (score 1):

One problem, that I ran into recently when upgrading a 3.5 project to 4.0 (Visual Studio 2008 to Visual Studio 2010), was that after upgrading to 4.0 I did not have a reference to `System.Core` and was unable to add it via Visual Studio instead displaying a message:

> A reference to 'System.Core' could not be added.  This component is already automatically referenced by the build system.

You will need to have a reference to `System.Core` if you want to use the `var` keyword and [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query) extension methods.

It can be manually added (or readded if removed). See the blog post *[System.Core in VS2010 Projects](http://stevesmithblog.com/blog/system-core-in-vs2010-projects/)* for details.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you migrated your Visual Studio solution to 2010, but you forgot to change the target framework to 4.0 in projects' properties.

Just go to properties in your solution projects (obviously, the migrated to Visual Studio 2010 solution) and change the target framework to 4.0.

That's all your C# code base will be using .NET Framework 4.0 and C# 4.0. I'm pretty sure you won't need to change your code, but, maybe, you'll find that some classes, methods, properties are now obsolete, but it'll compile anyway.

Comment out if you don't know how to do that.

Comment: Cant I use VS 2008 for working on .NET 4.0 and C# 4.0 feature, assuming I have installed .NET 4.0 on my PC .

Comment: No, sadly, you can't do that with VS2008.

Comment: So how do I do it without VS 2010 . A developer can develop C# applications in Sharpdevelop , or in notepad also. How does he / she use the new C# 4.0 features.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, C# 4 should be backwards compatible with C# 2.
In practice, I've done it several times with no problems, and I think the only obvious problem is if you have named some classes that are defined by the .net 4.0 framework.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use .NET 4.0 specific features in an application targeting .NET 2.0. You will need to migrate to .NET 4.0.

Comment: . that was exactly my question. What are the changes I should do for targeting my application to .NET 4.0.

Comment: Do we need to make any changes in code if migrating from .NET 2.0 to .NET 4.5?

Answer (score 0):

You *can't* easily convert form a higher version to a lower version.

You *can* easily convert form a lower version to a higher version.

Answer (score -1):

C# in .NET 2.0 does not support optional parameters if I remember correctly.

Comment: You can `target` .NET 2.0 and make use of the Optional parameters so long as you're using the C# 4 compiler.